Adding colour to a phylogenetic tree and using different data
I am posing the question from the one I had asked previously:
Any new and nice way to plot phylogenetic tree in LaTeX from an external csv file?
I had calculated a new tree from a subset of the original data. I also added the column colour to colour the label tips, but before I could modify the code to accommodate that, I thought it best to run the code as is and see if it renders correctly. However, it doesn't. I am getting two pages, one small and the other super long.
Here is the code I am using:
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.csv}
parent,node,branch.length,label,isTip,x,y,branch,angle,colour
90,1,4.44187158080376,Scenedesmus,TRUE,50,44,47.7790642095981,264.255319148936,green
92,2,4.44187158080376,Chlorella vulgaris,TRUE,50,30,47.7790642095981,183.829787234043,green
92,3,4.44187158080376,Chlorella sorokiniana,TRUE,50,31,47.7790642095981,191.489361702128,green
81,4,14.2981545428066,Haematococcus lacustris,TRUE,50,49,42.8509227285967,294.893617021277,green
87,5,4.44187158080376,Chlamydomonas zebra,TRUE,50,57,47.7790642095981,340.851063829787,green
84,6,4.44187158080376,Chlorococcum pamirum,TRUE,50,53,47.7790642095981,317.872340425532,green
91,7,4.44187158080376,Coelastrella,TRUE,50,46,47.7790642095981,279.574468085106,green
83,8,9.85628296200285,Dunaliella salina,TRUE,50,51,45.0718585189986,302.553191489362,green
72,9,9.85628296200285,Graesiella emersonii,TRUE,50,25,45.0718585189986,153.191489361702,green
85,10,9.85628296200285,Carteria lunzensis,TRUE,50,55,45.0718585189986,329.36170212766,green
87,11,4.44187158080376,Chlamydomonas hydra,TRUE,50,58,47.7790642095981,344.68085106383,green
90,12,4.44187158080376,[Chlorella] fusca,TRUE,50,45,47.7790642095981,271.914893617021,green
86,13,9.85628296200285,Neodesmus pupukensis,TRUE,50,40,45.0718585189986,241.276595744681,green
73,14,22.331072727605,Chlorosarcinopsis aggregata,TRUE,50,32,38.8344636361975,195.31914893617,green
61,15,50,Pavlova noctivaga,TRUE,50,1,25,7.65957446808511,orange
89,16,4.44187158080376,Enallax,TRUE,50,42,47.7790642095981,248.936170212766,green
89,17,4.44187158080376,Enallax costatus,TRUE,50,43,47.7790642095981,256.595744680851,green
91,18,4.44187158080376,Coelastrella oocystiformis,TRUE,50,47,47.7790642095981,283.404255319149,green
75,19,9.85628296200285,Valeriella excentrica,TRUE,50,35,45.0718585189986,210.63829787234,green
75,20,9.85628296200285,Spongiochloris spongiosa,TRUE,50,36,45.0718585189986,218.297872340426,green
72,21,9.85628296200285,Mucidosphaerium pulchellum,TRUE,50,26,45.0718585189986,157.021276595745,green
88,22,4.82044018144044,Micractinium pusillum,TRUE,50,29,47.5897799092798,172.340425531915,green
87,23,4.44187158080376,Chlamydomonas,TRUE,50,59,47.7790642095981,352.340425531915,green
82,24,4.44187158080376,Cymbella microcephala,TRUE,50,18,47.7790642095981,111.063829787234,brown
77,25,4.44187158080376,Ulnaria acus,TRUE,50,10,47.7790642095981,65.1063829787234,brown
78,26,4.44187158080376,Fragilaria pinnata,TRUE,50,8,47.7790642095981,45.9574468085106,brown
77,27,4.44187158080376,Ulnaria ulna,TRUE,50,11,47.7790642095981,68.936170212766,brown
68,28,18.2280571589398,Achnanthes,TRUE,50,13,40.8859714205301,84.2553191489362,brown
79,29,14.2981545428066,Gomphonema clavatum,TRUE,50,17,42.8509227285967,103.404255319149,brown
68,30,18.2280571589398,Navicula cincta,TRUE,50,14,40.8859714205301,88.0851063829787,brown
80,31,14.2981545428066,Tetraedron minimum,TRUE,50,37,42.8509227285967,225.957446808511,green
91,32,4.44187158080376,Coelastrella terrestris,TRUE,50,48,47.7790642095981,291.063829787234,green
85,33,9.85628296200285,Chloromonas,TRUE,50,56,45.0718585189986,333.191489361702,green
80,34,14.2981545428066,Pseudopediastrum boryanum,TRUE,50,38,42.8509227285967,229.787234042553,green
87,35,4.44187158080376,Chlamydomonas reinhardtii,TRUE,50,60,47.7790642095981,356.170212765957,green
63,36,36.6743852575887,Peridinium bipes,TRUE,50,6,31.6628073712056,30.6382978723404,blue
81,37,14.2981545428066,Ettlia,TRUE,50,50,42.8509227285967,298.723404255319,green
70,38,4.44187158080376,Trentepohlia aurea,TRUE,50,22,47.7790642095981,130.212765957447,green
70,39,4.44187158080376,Trentepohlia odorata,TRUE,50,23,47.7790642095981,141.702127659574,green
72,40,9.85628296200285,Auxenochlorella pyrenoidosa,TRUE,50,27,45.0718585189986,160.851063829787,green
62,41,4.44187158080376,Euglena gracilis,TRUE,50,3,47.7790642095981,15.3191489361702,pink
61,42,50,Cyanophora paradoxa,TRUE,50,2,25,11.4893617021277,black
66,43,29.4365141549397,Monomastix,TRUE,50,21,35.2817429225301,126.382978723404,green
71,44,24.8936909472995,Scherffelia dubia,TRUE,50,24,37.5531545263502,145.531914893617,green
83,45,9.85628296200285,Spermatozopsis similis,TRUE,50,52,45.0718585189986,310.212765957447,green
68,46,18.2280571589398,Achnanthidium minutissimum,TRUE,50,15,40.8859714205301,91.9148936170213,brown
82,47,4.44187158080376,Cymbella affiniformis,TRUE,50,19,47.7790642095981,118.723404255319,brown
68,48,18.2280571589398,Nitzschia palea,TRUE,50,16,40.8859714205301,99.5744680851064,brown
72,49,9.85628296200285,Nannochloris,TRUE,50,28,45.0718585189986,168.510638297872,green
64,50,33.8982155195864,Cosmarium,TRUE,50,20,33.0508922402068,122.553191489362,green
62,51,4.44187158080376,Euglena hiemalis,TRUE,50,4,47.7790642095981,19.1489361702128,pink
62,52,4.44187158080376,Euglena longa,TRUE,50,5,47.7790642095981,26.8085106382979,pink
78,53,4.44187158080376,Fragilaria radians,TRUE,50,9,47.7790642095981,53.6170212765958,brown
86,54,9.85628296200285,Tetradesmus obliquus,TRUE,50,41,45.0718585189986,245.106382978723,green
74,55,9.85628296200285,Pleurococcus,TRUE,50,33,45.0718585189986,199.148936170213,green
80,56,14.2981545428066,Kirchneriella,TRUE,50,39,42.8509227285967,233.617021276596,green
84,57,4.44187158080376,Chlorococcum humicola,TRUE,50,54,47.7790642095981,325.531914893617,green
74,58,9.85628296200285,Stigeoclonium tenue,TRUE,50,34,45.0718585189986,206.808510638298,green
65,59,31.5186414584415,Botrydiopsis,TRUE,50,7,34.2406792707793,34.468085106383,yellow
77,60,4.44187158080376,Ulnaria danica,TRUE,50,12,47.7790642095981,76.5957446808511,brown
85,87,5.41441138119909,Chlamydomonas,FALSE,45.5581284191963,58.5,42.8509227285967,348.510638297872,green
86,89,5.41441138119909,Enallax,FALSE,45.5581284191963,42.5,42.8509227285967,252.765957446809,green
86,90,5.41441138119909,Scenedesmus,FALSE,45.5581284191963,44.5,42.8509227285967,268.085106382979,green
86,91,5.41441138119909,Coelastrella,FALSE,45.5581284191963,47,42.8509227285967,287.234042553192,green
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{csvsimple-l3}
\usetikzlibrary{ext.misc}
\begin{document}\sffamily
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  conns/.initial=,
  node every node/.style={name=\nodeID, at={(\angle:\radius)}},
  node TRUE/.style={
    shape=circle, node contents=\nodeLabel,
    /utils/if={and(\angle>90,\angle<270)}
      {rotate=180+\angle, anchor=east}
      {rotate=    \angle, anchor=west}},
  node FALSE/.style={shape=coordinate, node contents=},
  do/.style 2 args={
    insert path={
      (#1) arc[start angle=\GET{#1}{angle},
               end   angle=\GET{#2}{angle},
               radius     =\GET{#1}{radius}] -- (#2)}},
  scale=.25, thick]
\newcommand*\GET[2]{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/conns/#1/#2}}
\csvreader{\jobname.csv}{
  parent = \parentID,
  node   = \nodeID,
  label  = \nodeLabel,
  isTip  = \isTip,
  x      = \radius, % we use a better macro name than \x
  angle  = \angle
  % what are these?
%  y      = \y,
%  branch.length=\branchLength,
%  branch = \branch,
}{
  \node[node every node, node \isTip];
  \tikzset{
    conns/\nodeID/angle/.initial/.expanded=\angle,
    conns/\nodeID/radius/.initial/.expanded=\radius,
    conns/.append/.expanded={[do={\parentID}{\nodeID}]}}
}
\draw\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/conns};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

What I have tried:

Removing the colour column to run the script.

Result: Still getting the same output.

Ran the old code from the previous post to make sure that still works.

Result: Yes, it does (duh).

Tried to remove chunks of the data from the filecontent part of the code of the old post.

Result: That also works!
So it seems that the previous code works even when you artificially subset it by removing some of the data. But when I calculate a different tree and try to use the old code, it can't seem to plot it correctly. Would it therefore be possible to tweak it so it can run other data? Or am I missing something very obvious?

Well, the first two rows say their parent are 92 but there's no row where that ID shows up in the node column. TikZ can't connect a node to a parent if that parent isn't existing. The same seems to be true for a bunch of other nodes judging by the error messages as well.

Re 3. Yes, it works because the csv is only written to the disk if the file is missing. So your TeX source doesn't truly represent the data on your disk. The filecontents environment is only used in the answer to have both the TeX file as well as its data in one piece. You don't have to use it. Just put your csv file where your TeX distribution can find it (in the same folder of your tex file is a good starting point).

Once you have your data properly, you can simply add , colour = \colour to the second argument of \csvreader and use it as text=\colour or even just \colour as an option to the node.

It sounds like the question is about what happens on your computer and is as such unanswerable.
If I remove the line \draw\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/conns}; (gives error and does not make sense), I get this output. You should be able to get the same with a new file with a new name.

Maybe you want to overwrite(could be dangerous) the data each time you run the code!? -use
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.csv}


Thank you for your answer, but why do this think this problem is unique to my computer? Clearly even you are having trouble compiling it correctly?

Do I have trouble compiling it? Please explain. It compiles fine on my computer(when the nonsensical line is removed) and it does not make two pages as you get.

Apologies. I wrote the wrong word. I meant that since the final "output" wasn't what was expected, I assumed that the problem was common.
